# MPI number of cores

Tags: c, mpi

Where can i specify or see the number of cores in MPI programm in C.
In other words I improved a programm written in c (MPI fox algorithm) which runs for 2 cores but actually I want to change it in order to run for 4 cores...
The program uses cartesian topology.

Comment: Did you hardcode the algorithm to only work for 2 cores? If not, you specify the number of cores when you run the program with `mpirun` or `mpiexec`. But it's not at all clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

You specify the desired number of proceses to the SPMD/MPMD launcher `mpiexec` (or `mpirun`), usually as

```
mpiexec -n <# of processes> <other options> ./executable <arguments>
```

Then you can find out the number of MPI processes launched by querying for the size of the world communicator:

```c
int nprocs;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WOLRD, &nprocs);
printf("There are %d processes running in this MPI program\n", nprocs);
```

If the program is also a hybrid MPI+OpenMP code, then the number of threads in each process could be controlled by setting the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable, unless the number is overridden in the code by a call to `omp_set_num_threads()` or with explicit `num_threads` clauses applied to the `parallel` regions.

Comment: When I run my program with 4 processors (mpiexec -n 4 ./test), it works properly but when I try to run it with less or more than 4 processors the program displays the following message:

Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_rank: Invalid commucicator, error stack,
PMPI Comm_rank(109) ...
PMPI Comm_rank(66) : Null comunicator

Comment: This often happens when the code is not written as to handle cases where the number of processes is larger. In this case a communicator handle is not initialised properly in all processes. May be it has the Cartesian topology hardcoded to be a 2x1 one, in which case the Cartesian communicator handle would be returned as `MPI_COMM_NULL` in half of the processes.